# Google Maps API blocked being blocked

Tags: google-maps

The company I work for uses Fujitsu Q665 tablets for a fleet managing software that is web-based.  It is called Geotab and it uses Google Maps for it's map source.

Unfortunately I receive some errors:

GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&language=en-US&callback=id09400674983401085&client=gme-geotab net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Failed to load provider: googlev3 RequiredScripts?i=GCU.map&x=geotab.default:541

Uncaught (in promise) 
Object {url: //maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&langua…US&callback=id09400674983401085&client=gme-geotab", xhr: XMLHttpRequest, message: "The page could not be displayed", isSevere: false}

I am able to run the UI (Geotab) using a different map source they offer, however not Google.

I believe some sort of firewall rule or network setting is causing this issue, however I can't pinpoint the issue.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Are you in the office when trying to use the software? Have you tried visiting the URLs that are failing to resolve in the browser?

Comment: Jack, I am in the office when using the software.  However this issue occurs regardless of the network I'm on.  Furthermore, when trying to visit the URLs listed above, I get a "This site can't be reached" message. 
Message, "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN